# Remove indentation and have all html in one line

Tags: html, xml, xslt, escaping, teamsite

I am trying to have all my HTML code in one line on TeamSite but when I save the DCR, it is automatically indenting all the code. Is there a way I can escape all the indentation and have one block of code? I tried using some HTML characters or commenting out the white space but it did not work or I might have not used it in the right way. Or if there's some feature on TeamSite that will help. Appreciate the help. Thanks!

What I want:
[image]

What I get:
[image]

Comment: What is the problem with having formatted code?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. The output file that is being generated is invalid json. I tested and with just one block of code and the json is valid. To change json format,  I need to change the presentation.xsl file. I want to see if there's an option without changing the presentation.xsl file.

Comment: JSON is not whitespace sensitive and can be minified. The formatting issues should not affect it. Also, why does it look like it is HTML in XML source code?